# Create loading state that is not inherited by segments below the tree

Tags: next.js, next.js13

NextJS allows to create a `loading.tsx` files that will be used [to show a loading state](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming#instant-loading-states) to the user before the server data is done fetching. This is useful but the problem I have is that if a have a tree like this:

```
cart/
  page.tsx
  layout.tsx
  loading.tsx
  summary/
     page.tsx
```

then the page `/cart/summary` will "inherit" the loader from page `/cart` page. How can I prevent it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I think that [route groups](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups) could be what you are searching for, since they also can be used for multiple-root-layout scenarios.